# Input a value to be used instead of (FDEFINITION 'COMP

Tags: common-lisp

clisp：

```
(defun sorted (seq comp)
(or 
    (< (length seq) 2)
    (and (comp  (car seq) (car seq))
        (sorted (cdr seq) comp)
    )
))
```

on ubuntu, run clisp ：

> (sorted '(1 3 4) ＃'<)

ERROR：USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of (FDEFINITION 'COMP).

how fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things amiss in your code.

First, in Common Lisp, data and functions live in separate namespaces. For this reason, you cannot use `(comp x y)` to call the function referred to by the variable `comp`. You have to use the `funcall` function.

Second, you are comparing `(car seq)` with `(car seq)` - that is, with itself. You probably meant to say `(car (cdr seq))`, which refers to the second element in the list.

After these changes, the code works correctly:

```
(defun sorted (seq comp)
  (or (< (length seq) 2)
      (and (funcall comp (car seq) (car (cdr seq)))
           (sorted (cdr seq) comp))))

* (sorted '(1 3 4) #'<)
T
* (sorted '(1 4 3) #'<)
NIL
```

Evaluating `(length seq)` on every iteration of your function is not efficient; to get the list's length, the system must go through the entire list. Effectively, your code will spend quadratic time doing a linear operation. It would be better to replace that with a simple end check.

Also, I would use the functions `first` and `second` instead of `(car seq)` and `(car (cdr seq))`, and `rest` instead of `cdr`. It is better to explicitly state in your code what you mean with it.

With these changes, the final code looks like this:

```
(defun sorted (seq comp)
  (or (endp (rest seq))
      (and (funcall comp (first seq) (second seq))
           (sorted (rest seq) comp))))
```

Comment: It should also be noted that the Common Lisp standard does not guarantee tail call optimization, so using recursion to simulate iteration is _not_ idiomatic, because it is not portable.  I would use `(every comp list (rest list))` (I renamed `seq` to `list` because `rest` only works with lists, not with all sequences.  If you want it to work with all sequences, use `subseq` instead of `rest`, but you need to add bounds checks then).